# no GroupLayout in NetBeans 7, what's wrong?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

Something wrong, I can't choose GroupLayout in NetBeans 7, I'm using Java 1.6

> java version "1.6.0_26" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
> 1.6.0_26-b03)
>
> NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 (Build 201107282000)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the "Free Design" is the Group Layout. Look at the source.